# iterate a dataframe to find connected rows-- do I need to convert each row to dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, spark-graphx

I have a function below that takes two dataframes and returns a dataframe.

```
def doJoin (df1: DataFrame, df2: DataFrame): DataFrame={
  val cols = df1.columns
  val r = df1.join(df2, cols.map(c => df1(c) === df2(c)).reduce(_ || _) )
    .select(cols.map(df1(_)) :_*)
    .distinct  
  return r
}
```

The problem is that now I want to loop through `df2`, and perform this for each row (in other words, treat each row as a df and pass it to that function). I tried things like `df2.foreach(map((a => (a.getInt(0), a.getString(1)))))` but the error that missing parameter type. How should I do this? Many thanks!

Example: Given input df1

```
Col1    Col2 
 1         30    
 2         30
 3         70 
 2         40
 4         90
```

I want to take each row of it, and find all the connected cell in the table. so for (1,30), the expected output is

```
1      30
2      30 //as (2, 30) is connected to (1,30) through 30
2      40 //as (2, 40 ) is connected to (2, 30) through 2
```

and then take another row (2, 30) to do the same thing.  Or is it more of a use case of GraphX api?

Comment: You should never "iterate a dataframe and convert each row to dataframe", can you give some example input and expected output?

Comment: Also: 1) You should probably not use `foreach` with a `map` like that, is this what you want `df2.map(a => (a.getInt(0), a.getString(1)))`? 2) You should not use the `return` keyword, simply end the method with `r` in the last line, see [here](https://tpolecat.github.io/2014/05/09/return.html).

Comment: @Shaido thanks. I edited the question. Let me know if I'm not explaining it well.